# Eclipse Mars bug with Map.Entry methods when using streams?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-stream

I am unable to see `Entry` `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods when collecting from the stream as Eclipse only offers `Object` methods, although everything compiles normaly.

```
someMap.entrySet().stream()
                  .filter( entry -> entry.getKey().isConsumed() || entry.getKey().getSurvivalCount() > 0)

                   // this compiles but auto-completion only offers object methods
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> entry.getValue()));
```

**Is this Eclipse bug or i am missing something ?**

I am using: 
Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

Image for visualization:

[image: eclipse playing tricks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse is happy when I specify the Predicate as an anonymous inner class:

```
Predicate<Entry<String, Integer>> predicate = new Predicate<Entry<String, Integer>>() {
    public boolean test(Entry<String, Integer> entry) {
        return entry.getKey() == null || entry.getKey().length() > 6;
    }
};
// ...
someMap.entrySet().stream().filter(predicate)
```

However, the lambda is problematic. There used to be other bugs with eclipse, e.g. it didn't even compile, like [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432110) or [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=469753) one.

So, it looks like you found a bug with lambda and code complete.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) Build id: 20160218-0600 and I experience the same issue as you.

It looks like a bug as it recognizes `entry` variable as an object of type `Entry`. I couldn't find this bug in Eclipse [bug list](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/query.cgi) though.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12409174)

Comment: @Matsemann The question is "Is this Eclipse bug or i am missing something ?". How is: "I experience the same issue as you. It looks like a bug [...]" not an answer to that, and specifically, how could that possibly be interpreted by you as another question?